# MYSQL SUM The count value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to SUM the Count Value then divide it to 2 But sadly my query is wrong

```
**This is my actual Database**
id|      date_opened    |
1 | 2021-03-05 11:27:31 |
2 | 2021-03-05 11:27:31 |
3 | 2021-03-05 00:03:45 |
4 | 2021-03-05 00:04:02 |
5 | 2021-03-04 00:00:05 |
6 | 2021-03-03 00:00:00 |
7 | 2021-03-03 08:46:33 |
```

And what I did is I count the same value (date)

**My query to Count Same Value (Working)**

```
SELECT COUNT(DATE(date_opened)) as 'Total User for this Date'
FROM daily_report
WHERE DATE(date_opened)>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY )
GROUP BY DATE(date_opened) DESC
```

**This is the result of the query above**

```
   |Total User for this day|
   |          4            |
   |          1            |
   |          2            |
```

and then I add the Sum Function and divide it to two

```
SELECT SUM('Total User for this Date') FROM (
SELECT COUNT(DATE(date_opened)) as 'Total User for this Date'
FROM daily_report
WHERE DATE(date_opened)>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY )
GROUP BY DATE(date_opened) DESC)/2
```

And i got this error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 5

```
    This is what I want to hapen
       |Total User for this day|
       |          3.5           |
```

Is it possible to Sum the Count data and divide it to 2 in Mysql? if it is, Can someone teach me to do it or just point me to right direction

Comment: Please post precise queries texts - there is no `'LIMIT 0, 25'` substring in them now...

Comment: Okay Okay Post the Disred output right?

Comment: Use backticks for column names quoting, not single quotes. Now you try to sum not column values but string literal `'Total User for this Date'`. And subquery cannot be divided (`/2`).

Comment: *Post the Disred output right?* No. Post real, not edited, SQL queries texts.

Comment: How is 7 / 2 == 2?  I am confused.

Comment: Sorry about that it was a typo by the way backticks is not working

Comment: If you just need sum()/2 why do you bother with the sub-query?  I.e. throwing a solution at you to see what I am missing.

Comment: Sorry I'm new in MYSQL  I did not use sum()/2 because I THINK  there is no integer in my database

Comment: And again - error message **does not match** the query text !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/2 as `Total User for this Day`
FROM daily_report
WHERE date_opened >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```